# Is there an easy way to convert Magento module name to composer names and vice versa?

Tags: magento2, module, composer

I am in a process where I want to compare two columns in my spreadsheet. The problem is one column has Magento module names (like `Magento_Swatches`). The other one has composer names (like `magento/module-swatches`).

****Question:** Is there an easy way to convert those name this without manual work?**

`Magento_Swatches` to `magento/module-swatches`

`magento/module-swatches` to `Magento_Swatches`

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you are looking for - to include or not 3rd party modules.

1. Modules can have completely different names in the `composer.json` files VS the module name in the `registration.php`. Also, I can create an extension and register multiple modules within it like this:

```json
{
    "name": "test/custom",
    "description": "My custom modules",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "require": {
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Test\\first\\":  "Test/module-first/",
            "Test\\second\\": "Test/module-second/",
            "Test\\third\\":  "Test/module-third/"
        },
        "files": [
            "Test/module-first/registration.php",
            "Test/module-second/registration.php",
            "Test/module-third/registration.php"
        ]        
    }
}
```

so basically you can't tell by the name in the composer.json which is the name of the module.

2. But if you need to only consider the Magento core, then I think it's safe to assume that the convention for [package name](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/build/composer-integration.html#package-name) and the ones for [component names](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/build/component-registration.html) are applied properly. From what I have seen it's accurate in the core modules, so you could use the logic you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And what is the best way to generate a list?